# Bracket Abstraction in Prolog

Tags: lambda, prolog

The algorithm "A" according to Antoni Diller looks fairly simple:

[image]

http://www.cantab.net/users/antoni.diller/brackets/intro.html

Can we do this in Prolog?

Comment: Thank you. Now I have more to read.

Comment: My answer has also a link to a fine paper.

Answer (score 3):

```
% associate formulas to left
associate_left(F, A, B) :-
    append(A, [B], F).

% apply algorithm
reduce(b(_, []), []).
reduce(b(A, B), 'K'(B)) :- atom(B), dif(A, B).
reduce(b(A, A), 'I').
reduce(b(A, [F]), R) :- reduce(b(A, F), R). % uncessary paranthesis case
reduce(b(A, F), 'S'(Pr, Qr)) :-
    associate_left(F, P, Q),
    reduce(b(A, P), Pr),
    reduce(b(A, Q), Qr).
```

I am assuming bound formulas are `b(x, F)` where x is bound in F.

```
?- reduce(b(x, [x]), A).
A = 'I' 

?- reduce(b(x, [y]), A).
A = 'K'(y) 

?- reduce(b(x, [u, v]), A).
A = 'S'('K'(u), 'K'(v))
```

Example from your link

```
?- reduce(b(x, [u, v, [w, z, x], [x, z, y], [z, x, [y, x]]]), A).
A = 'S'('S'('S'('S'('K'(u), 'K'(v)), 'S'('S'('K'(w), 'K'(z)), 'I')), 'S'('S'('I', 'K'(z)), 'K'(y))), 'S'('S'('K'(z), 'I'), 'S'('K'(y), 'I')))
```

I tried algorithm B too. It is a bit hairy but [here](https://gist.github.com/k3ut0i/e0b0323e54f0d7498dc4cd50273971a6) it is.

Comment: Cool! Your Prolog system might also have last/3. But with your coding of application I expected the results ['K', y] and ['S',['K',u],['K',v]], this would allow a full unlambda, i.e. for example converting b(y, b(x, [y])).

Comment: At first I encoded it as [const, y], [genapp, [const, u], [const, v]]. I changed it later to the current compound form for more traditional readability.

Answer (score 2):

Used a slightly different coding for application
with a Prolog operator that is already left associative:

```
?- X = ((a*b)*c).
X = a*b*c
```

And added a predicate unlambda/2:

```
unlambda(b(X,Y), Z) :- !,
   unlambda(Y, H),
   reduce(H, X, Z).
unlambda(P*Q, W) :- !,
   unlambda(P, R),
   unlambda(Q, S),
   W = R*S.
unlambda(X, X).

reduce(X, X, W) :- !,
   W = 'I'.
reduce(P*Q, Z, W) :- !,
   reduce(P, Z, R),
   reduce(Q, Z, S),
   W = 'S'*R*S.
reduce(X, _, 'K'*X).
```

But we see that there is a problem,
results can get quite long:

```
?- unlambda(b(x,b(y,x)), X).
X = 'S'*('K'*'K')*'I'
?- unlambda(b(x,b(y,b(z,(x*z)*(y*z)))), X).
X = 'S'*('S'*('K'*'S')*('S'*('S'*('K'*'S')*('S'*('K'*'K')*('K'*'S')))*
('S'*('S'*('K'*'S')*('S'*('S'*('K'*'S')*('S'*('K'*'K')*('K'*'S')))*
('S'*('S'*('K'*'S')*('S'*('K'*'K')*('K'*'K')))*('S'*('K'*'K')*'I'))))*
('S'*('K'*'K')*('K'*'I')))))*('S'*('S'*('K'*'S')*('S'*('S'*('K'*'S')*
('S'*('K'*'K')*('K'*'S')))*('S'*('S'*('K'*'S')*('S'*('K'*'K')*
('K'*'K')))*('K'*'I'))))*('S'*('K'*'K')*('K'*'I')))
```

We can use two identities already documented by Curien(*),
that have the effect of `[x]E = 'K'E` and `[x]Ex = E`:

```
reduce(P*Q, Z, W) :- !,
   reduce(P, Z, R),
   reduce(Q, Z, S),
   (S = 'I', R = 'K'*L ->
       W = L;
    S = 'K'*M, R = 'K'*L ->
       W = 'K'*(L*M);
       W = 'S'*R*S).
```

The result are much better now:

```
?- unlambda(b(x,b(y,x)), X).
X = 'K'
?- unlambda(b(x,b(y,b(z,(x*z)*(y*z)))), X).
X = 'S'
```

(*) See page 215 rule (abs) and rule (eta):
**Categorical Combinators**
P.-L. Curien - 1986
https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82017242.pdf