# Is there a higher order Prolog that wouldn't need a type system?

Tags: prolog, higher-order-functions, lambda-prolog

I suspect that λProlog needs a type system to make their higher
order unification [sound](https://www.lix.polytechnique.fr/Labo/Dale.Miller/lProlog/faq/what.html). Otherwise through self application some
Russell type anomalies can appear.

Are there alternative higher order Prologs that don't need .sig files?
Maybe by a much simpler type system, that doesn't need that many
declarations but still has some form of higher order unification?

Can this dilemma be solved?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a higher order Prolog that wouldn't need a type system?

These are type-free:

- [HiLog](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HiLog)
- [HiOrd](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-540-30502-6_7)

From the HiOrd paper:

> The framework proposed gives rise to many questions the authors hope to ad-
> dress in future research. In particular, a rigorous treatment must be developed for
> comparison with other higher-order formal systems (Hilog, Lambda-Prolog). For
> example, it is reasonably straightforward to conservatively translate the Higher-
> order Horn fragment of λProlog into Hiord by erasing types, as the resolution
> rules are essentially the same (assuming a type-safe higher-order unification pro-
> cedure).

- [Ciao](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ciao_(programming_language)) (includes HiOrd)

Comment: @MostowskiCollapse HO Babel has a type system

Comment: You judging from here, it has "data" https://www.scienceopen.com/document_file/2ae31345-97f3-4d5e-ba17-55640a59609c/ScienceOpen/001_Kuchen.pdf

Comment: @MostowskiCollapse HO Babel became Curry, I think. Its type system and syntax are very similar to Haskell's.

Comment: Hiord mentions bracket abstraction http://oa.upm.es/14365/1/HERME_ARC_2004-1.pdf , whereas λProlog seems to use deBruijn indexes under the hood. See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/65066544/502187 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/65346448/502187

Comment: **If** all above systems are a valid answer, then also regular [tag:iso-prolog]'s `call/N` counts. But this is only about higher-order programming, not higher-order logic.